# Building a classifier using Parzen window

Tags: nonparametric, density-estimation

Considering the application of the Parzen window method to model a probability density function in a binary classification problem, and assume a training set where the 4 points {−5, −1, 1, 5} belong to C1 and the 2 points {1, 2} belong to C2, a Gaussian kernel with a bandwidth equal to 1, what is the impact of having an occurrence (in this case, x=1) belonging to both classes?

Comment: This sounds like a homework, isn't it?

Comment: Yes. I mistakenly pasted the whole extract. My doubt is whether or not having the same point in both classes have any impact. My guess is not since we compute the likelihoods for each class separately, but having the same distribution centred in the same point contributing to both likelihoods seems strange.